# PHP Get Values Out of Checkbox Array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I am trying to figure out how to get values out of a checkbox array. The checkbox array var_dump looks like the following:

```
array (size=50)
0 => string '104702|0' (length=8)
1 => string '52278|1' (length=7)
2 => string '69891|1' (length=7)
3 => string '153335|1' (length=8)
4 => string '131140|1' (length=8)
. . .
```

I am sending two different IDs in each array value, separated by a pipe and would like to assign each part to different variables, $variable1, $variable2, so I can use them in a database query. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Even though I've accepted an answer below, here is the complete answer I was looking for:

To get the values out of the above array so I can use them in my database query, I did the following to first break them apart:

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $this->combinedIds[] = explode('|', $value);
}
```

Then, to get the values into separate variables, I did the following:

```
foreach ($this->combinedIds as $key => $value) {
    $firstId = $value[0];
    $secondId = $value[1]

    // do something with the values ...
}
```

Comment: Considering that you put an `explode` tag on the question, I am guessing that you at least have some idea as to how to approach this.  Can you show what you have done so far and indicate specifically where you are having problems?

Comment: No. This wasn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach loop on the array and explode each value with pipe symbol. Something like this :

```
foreach ($arr as $val) 
{
    $newData = explode("|", $val);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I did initially but didn't know how to get the values out.

Answer (score 0):

A different variant (using an anonymous function) would be something like:

`$values = array_map(function ($input) { $tmp = explode("|", $input); return ["id1" => current($tmp), "id2" => end($tmp)]; }, $array);`.

This is written for PHP 5.4+. If you need a version compatible with PHP 5.3 and downwards, just substitute the brackets with its corresponding `array(...)` equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting -- I wish I understood it. Can I use anonymous function inside a function in a class?

Comment: As far as my understanding of anonymous functions goes, yes but it depends where you want to use it. I use it as a parameter of the `array_map()` function, but you can define it in other places. You can do things like `$a = function($input) { return $input + 6; }` and the execute it like `$c = $a(5)` to get `11` as a result :P